# How do I check if a String contains restricted words using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

These are the strings that I should not allow in my address:

```
"PO BOX","P0 DRAWER","POSTOFFICE", " PO ", " BOX ",
 "C/O","C.O."," ICO "," C/O "," C\0 ","C/0","P O BOX",
 "P 0 BOX","P 0 B0X","P0 B0X","P0 BOX","P0BOX","P0B0X",
 "POBX","P0BX","POBOX","P.0.","P.O","P O "," P 0 ",
 "P.O.BOX","P.O.B","POB ","P0B","P 0 B","P O B",
 " CARE ","IN CARE"," APO "," CPO "," UPO ", "GENDEL",
 "GEN DEL", "GENDELIVERY","GEN DELIVERY","GENERALDEL",
 "GENERAL DEL","GENERALDELIVERY","GENERAL DELIVERY"
```

I created regular expression: This expression validates only POBOx part – please correct to not allow all the above strings in my address field

```
"([\\w\\s*\\W]*((P(O|OST)?.?\\s*((O(FF(ICE)?)?)?.?\\s*(B(IN|OX|.?))|B(IN|OX))+))[\\w\\s*\\W]*)+
|([\\w\\s*\\W]* (IN \s*(CARE)?\\s*)|\s*[\\w\\s*\\W]*((.?(APO)?|.?(cPO)?|.?(uPO))?.?\s*) [\\w\\s*\\W]*|([\\w\\s*\\W]*(GEN(ERAL)?)?.?\s*(DEL(IVERY)?)?.?\s* [\\w\\s*\\W]*))";
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: can you let me know some other ways to do it?

Comment: Can you explain more exactly what should match and what shouldn't? Maybe give some examples.

Comment: You can have a list of regexes and check against each one instead of trying to make a regex to end all regexes. More extensible, more readable, less lovecraftian.

Comment: You can put all the `string`s in a `HashSet` and query if the input already exists...

Comment: Using one regex for this is a very bad idea.  It's confusing, inefficient, and difficult to read and maintain.  I would just use basic string functions (ie _indexOf_).  If you _really_ want to use a regex (even though there's no advantage), I would use several smaller regexes one at a time (as Hanz has already suggested).

Comment: What do you think `[\\w\\s*\\W]*` match?

Comment: @jahroy: It's not inefficient. When you compile a Regex in `Java`, the library will turn it into a Determinstic Finite Automaton and do some minimisation on it, therefore the result will be evaluated with a lookahead of 0 and no backtracking.

Comment: Is `PORT` allowed or not?

Comment: @CommuSoft - That sounds nice but I'd be shocked if using _indexOf()_ doesn't destroy a large regex in a performance test... but maybe I'm dead wrong.  I wish I had time to build a test right now.

Comment: Normally it won't make a significant difference after (!) compilation of the regex (which happens at runtime).

Comment: @CommuSoft - That's good to know.  Someday I'll write a test and link to it here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're trying to see if an address string contains any restricted phrases.

**Please do not do this in one single regex.**

Doing one single massive regex matching query means it's hard to understand what you did to create the regex, hard to extend if more restrictions pop up, and generally not good code practice.

---

Here's a (hopefully) more sane approach:

```
public static final String RESTRICTIONS[] = { " P[0O] ", " B[0O]X ", "etc, etc" };

public static boolean containsRestrictions(String testString) {
    for (String expression : RESTRICTIONS) {
        Matcher restriction = Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(testString);
        if (restriction.find())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You're still doing regex matching, so you can put your fancy schmancy regex into your restrictions list, but it works on just plain old strings too. Now you only need to verify that each of the individual regexes work instead of verifying a giant regex against all possible cases. If you wanna add a new restriction, just add it to the list. If you're real fancy you can load the restrictions from a configuration file or inject it using spring so your pesky product people can add address restrictions without touching une ligne de code.

---

**Edit:** To make this even easier to read, and to do what you really want (restricting strings separated from other strings using whitespace), you can remove regexes altogether from the restrictions and do some basic matching work in your method.

```
// No regexes here, just words you wanna restrict
public static final String RESTRICTIONS[] = { "PO", "PO BOX", "etc, etc" };

public static boolean containsRestrictions(String testString) {
    for (String word : RESTRICTIONS) {
        String expression = "(^|\\s)" + word + "(\\s|$)";
        Matcher restriction = Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(testString);
        if (restriction.find())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Small addition to Hans' stuff above, I would compile in a static block or init method, or lazy-init compile them or some such.  Compiling Regex's can be expensive.

Comment: The performance hit probably wouldn't matter unless if there are a couple hundred thousand restricted words there. Static inits are just so... overkill.

Comment: A static init might not be your first choice, but compiling regular expressions **only once** is a good practice that should be done when possible.  For example, you could use an array of compiled Patterns to avoid compiling each regex every time you invoke _containsRestrictions()_, which would improve performance significantly.  As Taylor has mentioned, compiling a regex is very expensive compared to using one.

Comment: Agreed that static inits are teh suk (seemed the shortest step from your code sample), but assuming this is validating input in some (conceivably) high throughput (e.g. web), compiling all of those per request will not be fun.

Comment: @Taylor So I went home and mocked up a quick test, [you can see it here](https://github.com/hzhou-rmn/scratchpad/blob/master/main.java). I'm matching 10,000 restrictions (which is a ludicrous number of restrictions for this application). The final score: 43 ms for in-line compile vs 13 ms for pre-compile. That'a 30 ms difference. At a more reasonable 100 restrictions, the difference was 7ms for in-line vs 1ms for pre. That's 6ms per function call. I doubt any of you optimize any of your other functions to the tune of 6ms. Beware microoptimization at the cost of readability.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to search substrings like a pro? I'd suggest using the [Aho Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) which solves the kind of problems you have.

Selling point:

> It is a kind of dictionary-matching algorithm that locates elements of a finite set of strings (the "dictionary") within an input text. It matches all patterns simultaneously.

Luckily, a Java implementation exists. You can get it [here](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/java/index.html).

Here's how to use it:

```
// this is the part you have to do only once

AhoCorasick tree = new AhoCorasick(); 

String[] terms = {"PO BOX","P0 DRAWER",...};

for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
     tree.add(terms[i].getBytes(), terms[i]); 
}
tree.prepare();



// here comes the part you use for every address you want to check

String text = "The ga3 mutant of Arabidopsis is a gibberellin-responsive. In UPO, that is...";

boolean restrictedWordFound = false;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Iterator<SearchResult> search = (Iterator<SearchResult>)tree.search(text.getBytes());

if(search.hasNext()) {
    restrictedWordFound = true;
}
```

If a match has been found, `restrictedWordFound` will be true.

**Note:** this search is case sensitive. Since your strings are all in upper case, I'd suggest you first convert address in a temporary upper case variant and use matching on it. That way, you will cover all possible combinations.

From my tests, Aho Corasick is faster than regex based search and in most cases faster than naive string searching using `contains` and other String based methods. You can add even more filter words; Aho Corasick is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using such complicated regular expressions, you can state: the regex:

```
"PO BOX|P0 DRAWER|POSTOFFICE| PO | BOX |C/O|C.O.| ICO | C/O | C\0 |C/0|P O BOX|P 0 BOX|P 0 B0X|P0 B0X|P0 BOX|P0BOX|P0B0X|POBX|P0BX|POBOX|P.0.|P.O|P O | P 0 |P.O.BOX|P.O.B|POB |P0B|P 0 B|P O B| CARE |IN CARE| APO | CPO | UPO |GENDEL|GEN DEL|GENDELIVERY|GEN DELIVERY|GENERALDEL|GENERAL DEL|GENERALDELIVERY|GENERAL DELIVERY"
```

And negate the answer.

When you compile the regex (in `Java`) the resulting mechanism will become more efficiënt. (Java uses DFA minimalisation).

Comment: compiled regexes in Java are more performant than uncompiled. Yet the do not use a Thompson NFA nor a DFA (and thus no DFA minimalisation). that means exponential runtime in worst case.